# $E_6$ and the lines on a cubic surface

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, lie-groups, lie-algebras

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/E6_(mathematics)), in reference to the Lie algebra/group $E_6$,

> Its fundamental representation is 27-dimensional (complex), and a basis is given by the 27 lines on a cubic surface.

What is the meaning of this claim? Just a reference is fine.

Comment: It's hard to find a precise reference for the exact statement you want, but you can look at Manin's *Cubic forms,* specifically [Ch. IV](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0924-6509(08)70513-0). For example, Prop. 25.1 gives a basis for the Picard group of a cubic surface, the associated root system is identified as $E_6$ in Thm. 25.4, and the $(-1)$-curves are identified in Thm. 26.2. I couldn't find where Manin shows that these 27 $(-1)$-curves are indeed lines, but for that you can look at Thm. V.4.9 in Hartshorne.

Comment: @Takumi Murayama Thanks a lot.

Comment: Also Huybrecht's notes on cubic surfaces contain things which look a little like this.